# "Hesitate between A and B"

Tags: translation

Google Translate says that the sentence ["I hesitate between A and B" translates to](https://translate.google.fr/?sl=en&tl=ja&text=I%20hesitate%20between%20A%20and%20B&op=translate) :

> AとBの間{ま}で躊躇{ちゅうちょ}します

Is that correct ? I can't find sentences like this in Tatoeba or Weblio, but it looks like this is a common sentence.

Also, is there an other way to say this (synonym or other grammar structure) ?

Comment: As a side note: Beware that Google Translate isn't very good at Japanese and usually will give you poor and/or unnatural translations.

Comment: @Garbaz you're right, that's the main reason I asked because I feel like the translation was not good ! Usually, I use website like Weblio or Jisho to find sentences, but this one does not appear here :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's understandable, but it sounds very unnatural.

- 間 in a context like this is read あいだ.
- [迷う](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%BF%B7%E3%81%86) is the default verb you should use, and you have to use the teiru (progressive) form. 躊躇する usually means "to hesitate to take the action (despite knowing what to do)" or "to temporarily waver", and it's not a suitable choice when two options are equally possible.

You can say:

> AとBの間【あいだ】で迷って【まよって】います。

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you add some examples when 躊躇 is used please ?

Comment: @norbjd http://yourei.jp/%E8%BA%8A%E8%BA%87 It's used when you basically know what you have to do but want a little more time to make up one's mind. 迷う is used when you cannot pick one from multiple options.